# Is there a way to determine the IP address from which a uri was served from a mac/linux box?

Tags: linux, macos, command-line

I have a few servers behind a load balancer and I want to know which one is servicing a particular request.

`$ ping website.com` only tells me the ip address of the load balancer.  Is there a way I can tell what ip address `website.com/about?name=bob` is serviced from?

Comment: Can you modify the page that's behind the load balancer ?

Answer (score 0):

Only if you add an additional header (or other information) from the client, or if your load balancer logs the request and you can check those logs [ or by dumping traffic between balancer and web servers and analysing that ]